# How do get all html of #canvas with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to get all html inside canvas ID, all elements inside canvas have been created dynamically and the input element text has been updated on added text element. When using html() it only returns a value="Enter text" and not the updated one. I have already tried html(), get(0), find() and $("#canvas").[0] all sorts of things. Where am I missing it?

Thanks in advance.

**See below:**

```
    <div id="canvas" style="background-color: #fff; min-height: 30px; width: 80%" class="justify-content-center">
    </div>

<div class="ui-state-default ui-button-wrapper"><input type="text"  value="Enter Text" name="input" class="btn btn-info edit-btn text-btn"></div>


var textareainput = $("textarea").each(function(){
    var DOM_text = $(this).val();
    var editDOM = $(this).text(DOM_text)

});

var btnInput = $(".text-btn").each(function(){
    var btn_text = $(this).val();
    var editBtn = $(this).text(btn_text);
});

$(".ui-button-wrapper").each(function(){
    var DOMchildren = $(this).children();
    var DOM_btnText = $(this).children().val();
    var children = $(DOM_btnText).val();
    var inputHTML = $(this).html();
    var textinput = $(inputHTML).attr("value");
    var textValues = $(textinput).attr("value", textinput);
});

var htmlContent = $('#canvas').html();


    console.log(htmlContent)
```

Comment: where is #canvas in the html? how are you adding it dynamically?

Comment: The canvas is available in html, and i added the elements using jquery-ui for drag-and-drop